# Using special character in Enum e.g. % (C#3.0)

Tags: c#, enums, attributes, naming-conventions

I ahve a combo whose source is an Enum. Now , among the other values(say value1, value2

etc.) there is one item `Changes(%)` that will be displayed in the combo .

How to define Changes(%) in the enum?

Using C#3.0

Thanks

Comment: Are you just trying to display a list of strings one of which is "Changes(%)"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't. Enum value names have to be valid C# identifiers. You shouldn't be trying to put display names in there.

Instead, consider decorating each value with a `[Description]` attribute which you can fetch with reflection:

```
public enum ChangeType
{
    [Description("Changes (%)")]
    PercentageChanges,

    [Description("Changes (absolute)")]
    AbsoluteChanges
}
```

Alternatively define resources, possibly using the enum value name as the resource key. This will be better for i18n purposes, apart from anything else, although more work if you don't need your app to be internationalized.

EDIT: [Here's a WayBack machine archive of an article going into more detail](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203216/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/080410-1.aspx).

Comment: @priyanka: Well don't bind like that, basically. Binding directly to the values of an enum with no extra code and no template *will* show the value. I suggest you provide your combo box with an item template which fetches the relevant description.

Comment: I think the link I provided as supplementary-answer below has a good chance of visibility as a part of your accepted answer. http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/080410-1.aspx. Request a edit+add..if you deem it worthy.

Comment: article's broken

Comment: @jayrbayog: Fixed (in terms of using the WayBack machine to access an older version)

Answer (score 0):

C# enumerations compile out as sealed classes, inheriting from Enum, with public static fields carrying the name of your enumeration members, thus, you're asking the compiler to name fields things like "<", ">" and "=", and that's not accepted.

Enumeration values carry the same restrictions as properties and fields when it comes to naming.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW ... this article goes in-depth about the exact methodology of achieving what Jon Skeet suggests >>>> ... **[Pulling Enumeration Descriptions From A Resource File](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203216/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/080410-1.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

I use Jon's approach (a Description attribute against the enumerations) along with the extension method shown below to make it convenient to retrieve the description:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
  public static T GetAttribute<T>(this Enum enumerationValue) where T : Attribute
  {
    T[] attributes = GetAttributes<T>(enumerationValue);
    return attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0] : null;
  }

  public static string GetDescription(this Enum enumerationValue, string descriptionIfNull = "")
  {
    if (enumerationValue != null)
    {
      DescriptionAttribute attribute = enumerationValue.GetAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>();
      return attribute != null ? attribute.Description : enumerationValue.ToString();
    }
    return descriptionIfNull;
  }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
[TestClass]
public class WhenGettingDescriptionOfAnEnum
{
  private enum SampleEnum
  {
    First,
    [Description("description")]
    Second
  }

  [TestMethod]
  public void ShouldReturnNameOfEnumIfItHasNoDescription()
  {
    SampleEnum.First.GetDescription().Should().Be("First");
  }

  [TestMethod]
  public void ShouldReturnDescriptionIfThereIsOne()
  {
    SampleEnum.Second.GetDescription().Should().Be("description");
  }
}
```